# Linux: How to install certain old version of a software via apt-get

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, debian, version, apt-get

I am trying to install the same versions of Apache, MySQL and PHP in my Linux PC (Raspberry Debian) as installed in my remote public server.

For instance, I'd like to install the last legacy release of the 2.2 branch, Apache/2.2.31.

```
apt-cache showpkg apache2
```

Output:

```
Package: apache2
Versions: 
2.4.10-10+deb8u4 (/var/lib/apt/lists/mirrordirector.raspbian.org_raspbian_dists_jessie_main_binary-armhf_Packages)
```

But there isn't any information about the 2.2.31 version, neither in "Reverse Provides" section. I can do it by compiling from the sources, but it takes a lot of time. And I tried to find a reliable [PPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu#Package_Archives) or a reliable sources for deb packages, without any success.

How can I do it?

Comment: Re *"Raspberry Debian"*: Do you mean *"[Raspbian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Software)"*?

Answer (score 6):

**If** APT tracks the specific version you are looking for, (like Kyle said) then it's pretty easy.

```
sudo apt-get install <pkg_name>=<pkg_version>
```

*or*

```
sudo apt-get -t=<target_version> <pkg_name>
```

To see which packages are tracked, run

```
apt-cache showpkg <package_name>
```

Unfortunately though, if a particular version is not managed by the APT, then you are out of luck using APT. It might be managed by some of the other [package managers](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-package-management) out there.

Answer (score 0):

Ref. *[How can I downgrade a package via apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get)*

If you have the version number, or the target release, *apt-get* supports choosing a particular version or target release. More details can be found on manual page of *apt-get*. It can also be accessed from a terminal by typing *man apt-get*.

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>=<package-version-number>
```

*or*

```
sudo apt-get -t=<target release> install <package-name>
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install pkg_name=version`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However:
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install apache2=2.2.31
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.2.31' for 'apache2' was not found